# Git with Visual Studio 2015 (C#)

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015

Hello everybody and thanks always for the help
I would like to ask if there is a **simple, very simple** tutorial for using git with visual studio 2105.
"you can google it" you can say, ok, I already did it and I find first a cryptic and not so "basic" page in microsoft site and I also found this seemingly excellent video tutorial
[Using git with visual studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egy2r6ReaeI)

My problem is it does not work like that in my system.

1) I tried to put an existing project with source control but I dont know how to do that.

2) So, ok, let's start with the basics- I said, so I did what they did. *Create* a new project with source control and there the problems started

2-1) it does not ask me if I want git or the other one as in the video
2-2) the output window throw an error as

> We were unable to automatically populate your Visual Studio Team Services accounts.

The following error was encountered: TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

2-3) I get my basic code so I want to do my initial commit as they do in the video but the commit button is not active. No matter how many changes I make in the code, git does not register any change and therefore does not let me commit.

I don't want to do any fancy things, share my code, or even upload it to a repository, clone it anything. I just want the most **BASIC** thing, have my local repository and work with that

can anybody help me please?

Comment: edit out the part asking for a tutorial, as that's not a valid question for SO

Comment: Though I have been using Git for years, my advice is that you learn another client, such as GitKraken or TortoiseGit. The VS integration is in so many ways a wrong approach.

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions in your post and they're a bit disjointed. Visual Studio 2015 is the IDE; Git is the version control system. There are layers in between the two, and you should have some knowledge of what they are. Moreover, you can use VS2015 against local Git repos and you can sync those repos with a remote server. The remote server can be TFS or Visual Team Services. I would suggest first revising your post or breaking your questions up into different posts. I also would focus on working against a local repo before you even think of doing anything with a remote...

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. I just learned this stuff a few weeks ago. Form what you describe, you are not logged into VisualStudio.com inside of Visual Studio. Yes, I know that sounds really dumb, but I do think that is your problem.

Your real problem is that you are trying to learn two things at once, git and using git with VS as a shell. That will make it way harder.

I would suggest that you start using git from the command line first. That will help you understand how it works and then adding VS on top is less of a challenge since you will understand what SHOULD happen.

You can download the command line version of git [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads). Once you have mastered local repositories, you can create a GitHub account and practice with remotes. Once you have mastered that, then try using it from within Visual Studio.

Comment: thank you for your very useful reply. I solved some problems by relogin to there as you wrote. Does this mean that even for a local repository I have to be logged in ?? yeah that sounds dumb.  I have Git Bash here too. Will keep practicing,. Thanks again